# Joi validator object that contains other objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, joi

I get this type of json in the req body:

```
"customerDetails": {
    "contact": {
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
    },
    "address": {
        "addressSFID": "",
        "cityAddress": "",
    }
```

And I tried to use this schema:

```
customerDetails: Joi.object({
    contact: Joi.object({
        firstName: validateName(),
        lastName: validateName(),
    }),
    address: Joi.object({
        addressSFID: validateSfid(),
        cityAddress: validateGeneralAddressDetail(),
    })
}),
```

But it doesn't work. No error thrown but it doesn't validate the fields as it should and did

when it was two separate objects (the two inside `customerDetails`)

What syntax should I use?

Comment: if your problem is not solved, leave a comment, if my answer is true accept it, thank you

Comment: Hi, it was eventually a different mistake by me in the code. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing your schema once then you do not need to use `.keys()`. As use .keys() when added more lines `(keys)` to your object  like this :

```
Joi.object().keys({
  contact:Joi.object().keys({
        "firstName":Joi.string(),
        "lastName": Joi.string()
  }),
   address:Joi.object().keys({
        "addressSFID":Joi.string(),
        "cityAddress": Joi.string()
  })
})
```